# Sorting alphanumeric values in Power BI filter and SSAS tabular cube

Tags: powerbi, ssas-tabular, powerbi-filters

I have created a SSAS tabular cube using data from Views. One of the columns in a view contains alphanumeric data like `Y1, Y1.1, Y10, Y10.1, Y2, Y3.0`. I have managed to sort this column the correct way such that 10 comes after 9 instead of 1 like `Y1, Y1.1, Y2, Y3.0, Y10, Y10.1`.

But the sorting does not show in the Power BI report filter I am using this column in. In that filter the data remains unsorted. I am not using this column directly in the filter but instead I am using **Sort by Column** property with another column (as shown in the Microsoft's documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/tabular-models/column-properties-ssas-tabular?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15)) which contains just descriptions of the codes.

Can anyone please help me figure out what I am doing wrong here?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually figured out the solution to this problem. Even though I sorted the dataset on the most basic level of source code as well, sorted order didn't show in Power BI. What worked was setting the data type of numerical column which I was using to sort the rows to whole number.

Shown in the image below:

[image]

Where R1 is sorted and contains numbers which come right after the letters e.g `1, 1, 2, 3, 10`